# How long are Windows Server 2003 Active Directory credentials cached on Snow Leopard?

Tags: windows, accounts, login, active-directory

I have a few Macbooks that will be added to our Windows 2003 domain controller. Since these are mobile units, concerns arose of how long they (the machines) will maintain login rights after their last contact with the domain.

Comment: Which MacOS X version are you using?

Comment: Leopard and Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Active Directory password policies are enforced, so you are in control of this.  See this [resource](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.20/20.11/ActiveDirectory/index.html) for more information.